# Fetch is getting local and input url

Tags: javascript

Im trying to get from urlData the url to use on my fetch. But im getting an error, my fetch is getting the local and input url

```
function analyzeWebSite() {
  const urlData = document.getElementById('url_data');
  const url = urlData.value;
  if (url === '') {
    alert('You need to send a valid website.');
    return;
  }
  fetch(url).then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // show all response from the sended webpage
    return response.text().then(function (text) {
      console.log(text); // show all the text from the sended webpage
    });
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i forgot. Now its edited.

Answer (score 0):

The console error says 404 not found. I think you need to make sure the user adds `https` or `http` in the input.

Alternatively, you can modify the user's input:

```js
if(!url.match(/https?:\/\//)){
  url = "https://" + url;
}
```

Comment: the url is "http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.google.com.br", for some reason in  fetch(url) is getting my local url that is 127.0.0.1:5500. If its only "www.google.com.br" is working fine

Comment: important, urlData has only a string with 'www.google.com.br'

Comment: If you don't add protocol, request will find base on your local. It's like If you request url without "http://" on your browser(www.google.com or google.com), the actual browser requesting with "http://" (https://www.google.com).
Use the code in this answer to clarify the request address.